# CQ5.6.1- Log4j in Osgi bundle not detecting

Tags: log4j, osgi, aem

I am using a jar file given by my client in CQ5.6.1. Some classes in the jar file requires log4j. So I created a Osgi bundle having the client jar and log4j jar files using Eclipse. I installed this into the Osgi Bundles of CQ and activated the bundle. The class from the client jar is correctly invoked from my components jsp, but the client jar is not able to locate the log4j classes. I am getting the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator not found`. I also tried putting the log4j jar into the install folder under my app\ in CQ, but that also didn't help. I searched in google but couldn't find a suitable solution yet. Any help to resolve is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your log4j bundle needs to export the org.apache.log4j package, and the client bundle needs to import it. Sling scripts see all exported packages.

You can use the OSGi console at /system/console/bundles to verify that those exports and imports are correct, the client bundle's status page should show that it imports the package from the log4j bundle.

If the exports are correct, the cause might also be some log4j or client code loading the PropertyConfigurator using a thread context class loader (TCCL) or another mechanism that does not play well with OSGi. If it's TCCL you can work around the issues by setting that TCCL yourself around code that loads the PropertyConfigurator.

CQ does provide the slf4j logging APIs out of the box, so if you can convince your client to switch to those that's probably easier.